# Progressively enhancing html form, jQuery UI datepicker not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modernizr, progressive-enhancement, yepnope

I'm new to progressively enhancing HTML5 forms, and I'm currently trying jQuery UI and HTML5's new input types to create cross-browser forms. I'm using [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) and [Yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) for conditional loading of scripts and following tutorial given at [CSS-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/progressively-enhancing-html5-forms/). But I'm getting `Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'` error.

I found that there's `Modernizr.load()` which can be used in place of `yepnope()`, but that didn't worked and ended up with `Object #<Object> has no method 'load'` error so I went back to `yepnope()`. Below is by `<Head>` section of the webpage.

```
<Head>
    <title>HTML5 Web Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr-2.5.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/yepnope.1.5.2-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    yepnope({
            test: Modernizr.inputtypes.date,
            nope: [
                    "./js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js",
                    "./css/jquery-ui-1.8.17.css"
            ]
    });

    $(function(){
        $("input[type='date']").datepicker(); //this is giving error
    });
    </script>
</Head>
```

And the `<body>` has a form with `<input type='date' name='dtTest'/>`

After a bit Googling, I found that cause for the error is loading of jQuery Core twice, I also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934319/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method-datepicker), but can't fix the issue.

Thanks.

**Note**: I'm testing the page in Chrome 17 and Opera 11.61.

Comment: The only guess I can make at this stage is that the datepicker function is being called before your jQuery/jQuery UI is having a chance to load... have you tried calling the .datePicker() function on page load rather than immediately (as above)?

Comment: @MassivePenguin Its already in the DOM ready function.

Comment: from looking at the pages you linked it looks like your js files aren't being loaded in the order they're needed. I take it you've checked your browser's console to make sure all the scripts are actually being found and loaded correctly? Without seeing some live code there's not a lot more I can suggest, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what your HTML page should look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<Html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 Web Form</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr-2.5.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/yepnope.1.5.2-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            yepnope({
                test : Modernizr.inputtypes && Modernizr.inputtypes.date,
                nope : [
                    'js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.min.js',
                    'css/jquery-ui-1.8.17.css',
                    'js/datepicker.js'
                ],
                callback : {
                    'jquery-ui-1.8.17.min.js' : function() {
                         $("input[type='date']").datepicker();
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="lblTest">Hello World</div><br/>
        <form name="frmMain" action="#">
            Date : <input type='date' name='dtTest'/>
        </form>
    </body>
</Html>
```

And the content of datepicker.js should be:

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type='date']").datepicker();
});
```

This works fine on my copy of Chrome, though I've not had the chance to check it in other browsers.

**Update**: We can avoid using separate `datepicker.js` by making use of `callback` block of yepnope more efficiently and binding `datepicker()` there itself.

Comment: I already tried using callback, but that's not working at all, neither its giving any error in Inspector.

Comment: Can you post a link to the code? I can't see any issues with what you've posted, so I need to see it in context.

Comment: [Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30072126/WebForms.zip)'s the link to my test page and all the scripts

Comment: I've replaced my original answer with the code that I managed to get working. Hope it works for you too!